# Failing to get the value of an EditText in ViewHolder of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app, I have a RecyclerView with editable EditText views as part of the ViewHolder, see picture:

[image: RecyclerView with ViewHolders and EditText views]

The user can edit the values of the EditText views. To save the changed value back to the related adapter, set an OnFocusChangeListener to the EditText views, storing the (changed) value as soon as they loose focus, see following code snippet, taken from the onBindViewHolder method of my adapter:

```
// Add listener to views
        holder.fpuView.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                // Focus has gone, so save value to adapter
                mAbsorptionBlocks.get(position).setMaxFPU(Integer.valueOf(holder.fpuView.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
        holder.absorptionTimeView.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                // Focus has gone, so save value to adapter
                mAbsorptionBlocks.get(position).setAbsorptionTime(Integer.valueOf(holder.absorptionTimeView.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
```

This works fine, as long as the user taps another EditText view.

It does NOT work if the user directly hits the "Save" button immediately after having changed the value of the EditText. The EditText seems not recognize that is has lost focus. This is probably due to the Save button does not belong to the RecyclerView, but to the parent activity.

I played around with other listener options, but I'm pretty lost now. Is there any chance to grasp the changed values when the user hits the Save button directly after editing the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must these method of EditText

```
holder.fpuView.addTextChangedListener(new 
TextWatcher() {

 @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

  @Override    
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int 
  start,int count, int after) {
  }

  @Override    
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
  int before, int count) {
     if(s.length() != 0) {  
        mAbsorptionBlocks.get(position). setMaxFPU(Integer.valueOf(holder.fpuView.getText().toString()));
     }else{
            // add default value when EditText is empty. 
      }
```

}
});

Comment: Thanks, Bhavesh, this is the solution of my problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnTestChangeListener` instead. Then catch the after text changed event or in real time if you prefer. That way you aren't relying on the focus change event to get the text.